# R shiny output text not displaying

Tags: r, shiny, output

I have two dataframes, one to create a wordcloud and one to give a numeric output.

```
 d<- word    freq
      save  42
     earth  14
     life   14
     aug    12
    name    11
    wate    11
   group    10
   email    9
  ignore    6
  please    6


   DF4d<- word    freq
           save  4
           earth  1
           life   1
           aug    1
          name    1
          wate    1
         group    1
          email   9
          ignore  6
          please  6
```

Next I have set up the UI as follows to display a wordcloud based on das well as a numeric output derived based on DF4

```
    ui<- fluidPage(
    textInput("e-mailSubject", label = "SubjectLine",placeholder = 
          "'"),actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
      numericInput("Audience Size", label = "Target Audience Size", value = 
             c(10000000)),
     dateInput("Date",label = "Date of Campaign"),
     mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot1"), textOutput("Output1")))
```

The server contains inputs based on DF4 and d.

```
  server<-function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
  set.seed(1234)
  wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))   })
      output<-renderText(text2<-reactive({input$e-mailSubject
      mycorpus2<-Corpus(VectorSource(text2))
      mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, tolower)
      mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeNumbers)
      mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))

     dtm2<-TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus2)
     m2<-as.matrix(dtm2)
     v2 <- sort(rowSums(m2),decreasing=TRUE)
     d2 <- data.frame(word = names(v2),freq=v2)

     outputtable<-DF4[DF4$variable%in%d2$word,]
    outputresult<-sum(outputtable$sum.estimate.)
    return(outputresult)
    }))
        }
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am getting the wordcloud. WhenI enter a sentence in the input box and press the click me button, I am supposed to get output result. There is no error message. but I am not getting any result. I am not sure where my error is. i request someone to help me here. The output is supposed to be numeric

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but can't yet due to reputation - next time, please provide a reproducible example. (`wordcloud` etc need extra packages, which I don't know, so can't successfully run your code).

I suspect the problem is that your `textOutput("Output1")` doesn't show up in the `server` at all. Try this instead of the `...` part:

```
  text2 <- reactive({
    input$e - mailSubject
    mycorpus2 <- Corpus(VectorSource(text2))
    mycorpus2 <- tm_map(mycorpus2, tolower)
    mycorpus2 <- tm_map(mycorpus2, removeNumbers)
    mycorpus2 <-
      tm_map(mycorpus2, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))

    dtm2 <- TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus2)
    m2 <- as.matrix(dtm2)
    v2 <- sort(rowSums(m2), decreasing = TRUE)
    d2 <- data.frame(word = names(v2), freq = v2)

    outputtable <- DF4[DF4$variable %in% d2$word, ]
    outputresult <- sum(outputtable$sum.estimate.)
    return(outputresult)
  })


  output$Output1 <- renderText(text2)
```